# How can I plot two vectors of values versus dates? MATLAB

Tags: matlab

Hi I am new to MATLAB and need some help with making a matrix so that I can plot a figure of turnover rates on the NYSE. I have 4 vectors right now, `year`, `month`, `at` and `mt`.

They're uploaded from a `.csv` in the form of

```
2010 1 .99 .99
2010 2 .98 .98
2010 3 .99 .98
.    .  .   .
.    .  .   . 
2016 4 .99 .99
```

I'd like to be able to plot `at` and `mt` versus the dates on the x-axis ascending from Jan 2010 to April 2016. Right now I can plot `at` and `mt` versus a vector `z = 1:76` (as all these vectors are `76x1`) just to represent an increasing x.

If anyone can help that'd be awesome. Thanks.

EDIT: Here's my code thus far

```
year = data(:,1); %Year (2010, 2011...2016)
month = data(:,2); %Month (1,2,3,etc.)
mt = data(:,3); %NYSE Annualized Monthly Turnover
at = data(:,4); %NYSE Annualized Year to Date Turnover

z = 1:76;

a = plot(z, mt, 'r-', z, at, 'b-');
hold on
legend(a, 'Annualized Monthly Turnover NYSE', 'Annualized Year NYSE')
title('Annualized Monthly & Year-to-Date Turnover of NYSE Securities')
xlabel('Date')
ylabel('Turnover (x100%)')
hold off
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a date vector by matlab command datenum, then you can apply the datetick command in plot, such as plot(datetick(vector, 'mm-yyyy'), mt).

Answer (score 0):

```
year = data(:,1); %Year (2010, 2011...2016)
month = data(:,2); %Month (1,2,3,etc.)
mt = data(:,3); %NYSE Annualized Monthly Turnover
at = data(:,4); %NYSE Annualized Year to Date Turnover

z = 1:length(data(:,1));
```

#### Convert date values to string

```
x_axis_val =strcat(num2str (year),'/',num2str(month));
```

plot the graph

```
a = plot(z, mt, 'r-',z, at, 'b-');
hold on
legend(a, 'Annualized Monthly Turnover NYSE', 'Annualized Year NYSE')
title('Annualized Monthly & Year-to-Date Turnover of NYSE Securities')
xlabel('Date')
ylabel('Turnover (x100%)')
```

#### Add tick labels to the axis

```
set(gca,  'XTickLabel',x_axis_val) %adding x tick labels
hold off
```

Comment: Ok I have tried this but every tick on the x-axis is from Jan to Sept of just 2010, I would like it to do from 2010-2016